# "Debug Assertion Failed" on Vector

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, vector

Im aware that this question gets asked very often however for the life of me i cannot figure out where & why im getting an assertion failure. Could someone have a look please and see if im losing my mind?

```
int numMonsters = 0;
while(numMonsters < 40){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            gameMonsters.push_back(Monster(j, numMonsters));
            //cout << "Created new monster " << numMonsters << enld;
            numMonsters++;
        }
    }
}

int c = 0;
while(c < gameMonsters.size()){
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        for(int b = 0;  b < 20; b++){
            board[a][b] = gameMonsters[c].getMonsterNum(); //breaks here
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You start by putting 40 elements in your container.
 Then you proceed to attempt to access 200. Your two nested loops run for a total of 10 * 20 times.

That's not going to end well.